# Bing or Google maps for loading lots of data? and other questions

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, bing-maps

I have several questions here:

1. Which service to use (google vs bing) to display lots of (let say 100.000 and more) pushpins on the map?
2. What is a fastest way to do that, load all at the same time, or load 100 pushpins in the area you zoomed in, to use kml feeds.. (what about caching..?)
3. I would prefer Bing map, as it has nice birds' view. Is it a good approach to choose AJAX API vs web services or silverlight implementation for such task?
4. I tried Bing Map javascript API and when I run StartGeocoding(address), it points to the the street next to that address/house, when Bing Map online points directly to that house. How to reach the same precise results using javascript API?

I will have to display lots of places on the map, so I want to choose a right approach and service before starting a project.

Comment: you can op in to paid service with google map and that service might be better than the open source one.

Comment: I dont want to use paid service, as all my data is already geocoded and ready to use. Just need to display that on the map..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend google as well. I noticed that Bing is really big on Silverlight which i find to be more of a performance hog compared to javascript. I just like google's User Experience way better for Maps as well as their image searching/viewer (google's javascript version is faster and feels faster than Bing's silverlight counterpart).

Comment: Strange. I always felt exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google Fusion Tables. Add your data to a Fusion Table and then it can be displayed using the Google Maps API very efficiently.

Comment: Fusion table is just a plain table, like Excel. How is that more efficient than grabbing from database or json..?

Comment: Fusion Tables can render image based tiles server side to display on a map. This means it can be orders of magnitude faster to render large numbers of markers.